Best way to create teams bot with chat with your data
I've experience with botframework in C#/ Python and also I've come across the Teams toolkit in vs code as well. When it comes to chat with your own data by utilizing Azure Open AI, What's the best approach.
Bot framework Python + Langchain was very slow and session management was done using separate architecture.
I have to use streaming responses as well to make them faster. And bot framework python did not allow me to do that.
Looking for suggestions.

The chat with your own data example Microsoft provides in the chat playground of Azure AI Studio is a mix between cognitive search and GPT.

The process works (more or less) like this:

Upload your data to a share-point site or other storage area
Have cognitive search index the data
Send the user chat history (as much as possible) to GPT and ask it to generate a cognitive search query which is likely to identify the most relevant documents within your data.
Use the resulting query with cognitive search to identify relevant sources documents within your data.
Create a prompt which includes data from your top X sources (depending on their size) and ask GPT to formulate a response based on the included sources tell it to include its sources.

A full implementation (which I believe the chat with your data example is based on) can be found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo-csharp?tab=readme-ov-file
Streaming responses can be achieved by calling "UpdateActivityAsync" on the TurnContext each time you receive a new word from GPT.

Streaming responses can achieve only using C# right?

Updating messages is also possible in python. See (switch to the python tab) https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-conversation/python/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py#L156 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=python#update-messages
